# How can I rename a submit button text without failing the form?

Tags: php, html, button, submit

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input id="wpcr_submit_btn" name="submitwpcr_' . $post->ID . '" type="submit" value="' . $this->options['submit_button_text'] . '" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

OK, here is the code. The button text now is "submit your review" When I change the value it changes the button text as I want but it doesn't sent the results to me any more. Is there any way to change the text without loosing the connection?

[Here is the link to the file](http://bonjour-bg.com/other/wp-customer-reviews.txt)

Kind regards
Dimitar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your receiving script probably relies on the value of the `submit` - you have to edit it there as well to match your new value.

UPDATE: In your script find this line

```
'submit_button_text' => 'Ð˜Ð·Ð¿Ñ€Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸',
```

and edit the button text there, not directly in the HTML output (you have to revert back the code it had before)

Comment: `'submit_button_text' => 'Send',` Now I tried with the word "Send" but it doesn't change it. Go [here](http://bonjour-bg.com/?page_id=239)  to see the button. Simply click to extend the form.

Comment: Revert your button back to `<tr><td colspan="2"><input id="wpcr_submit_btn" name="submitwpcr_' . $post->ID . '" type="submit" value="' . $this->options['submit_button_text'] . '" /></td></tr>` and change the button text in the settings ONLY

Answer (score 1):

If you're using form-field checking on the server in your handling script to detect a POST, then changing the name on the client-side is obviously going to break your server-side script.

Instead of

```
if (isset($_POST['name_of_submit_button'])) {
    ... form was submitted
```

use

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... form was submitted
```

instead. This method is 100% reliable for detecting a post, and does not depend AT ALL on the presence/absence of particular form field names.

Answer (score 1):

Your reciving script, and your button are to tightly coupled.Editing your reciving script to  remove the coupling would solve the issue you have

Comment: Sounds easy to be done, but I don't have any idea how to remove the connection.

Comment: could you post your reciving script?